# How do I use the postal code overlay with fills and specific postal codes only?

Tags: javascript, here-api

```js
/**
 * Shows the postcode layer provided by Platform Data Extension REST API
 * https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/introduction.html
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function showPostcodes(map, bubble){
  var service = platform.getPlatformDataService();

  style = new mapsjs.map.SpatialStyle({ strokeColor: 'red', fillColor: 'rgba(0, 85, 170, 0.4)' });
  
  //style.setStyle({strokeColor:'Red'});

  
  // create tile provider and layer that displays postcode boundaries
  var boundariesProvider = new mapsjs.service.extension.platformData.TileProvider(service,
  {
    layerId: 'PSTLCB_GEN', level: 12
  }, {
      resultType: mapsjs.service.extension.platformData.TileProvider.ResultType.POLYLINE,
      styleCallback: function(data) {return style}
  });
  var boundaries = new mapsjs.map.layer.TileLayer(boundariesProvider);
  map.addLayer(boundaries);

  // create tile provider and layer that displays postcode centroids
  /*
  var centroidsProvider = new mapsjs.service.extension.platformData.TileProvider(service,
  {
    layerId: 'PSTLCB_MP', level: 12
  }, {
      resultType: mapsjs.service.extension.platformData.TileProvider.ResultType.MARKER
  });
  var centroids = new mapsjs.map.layer.MarkerTileLayer(centroidsProvider);
  map.addLayer(centroids);
  */

  // add event listener that shows infobubble with basic information
  // about the postcode
  centroidsProvider.addEventListener('tap', function(ev) {
    var marker = ev.target;
    bubble.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
    var str = '<nobr>Postal code: ' + marker.getData().getCell('POSTAL_CODE') + '</nobr><br>' +
              'Country code: ' + marker.getData().getCell('ISO_COUNTRY_CODE') + '<br>'
    bubble.setContent(str);
    bubble.open();
  });
}





/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'devportal-demo-20180625',
  app_code: '9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ',
  useHTTPS: true
});
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
  tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
  ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
});

//Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map, {pixelRatio: pixelRatio});

map.setCenter({lat:50.892710, lng:-0.916670});
map.setZoom(12);

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// create info bubble that is used to display the postcode data
bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(map.getCenter(), {
  content: ''
});
bubble.close();
ui.addBubble(bubble);

// Now use the map as required...
showPostcodes(map, bubble);
```

```html
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
<link href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1542186754" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; background: grey" />
```

I have this jsfiddle demo but im trying to ...

1. only show the boundary for the postal code containing the map center lat lon
2. fill the border with a colour

Link to jsfid -> /hectare/w0dves5j/

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Please add your code _to the question_. Don't just put it in a Fiddle as that link might get broken, making this question useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to this example:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/platformDataExtension/postcodes-jsla-pde

1. You can iterate through the given back polygons out of the PDE response, compare each of them with the map center and just display the polygon which inherits this center coordinate.
2. Filling of a polygon:

   ```
   new H.map.Polygon(lineString, {
     style: {
       fillColor: '#FFFFCC',
       strokeColor: '#829',
       lineWidth: 8
     }
   ```

Comment: The Geocoder API also has the abiliity to retrieve shapes of areas (including postal codes), which may be an easier way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @leopectus your answer has also got me there but I can't seem to convert the Shape data from the API into polygon friendly data. Any help would be gratefully received. https://jsfiddle.net/hectare/w0dves5j/22/

Comment: Thanks for all your help